# Playing MIDI-files and synchronizing time with visuals with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, midi, naudio

I'm writing an application using C#/Windows Presentation Foundation.
It is visualizing the steps of a dance with foot shapes.
Currently I'm playing the music as WAV-file and timing the steps with a Timer.

Because of the irregularities of a **Timer** the music is **not in sync** with the steps.
I need some kind of **synchronization**, this is why I wanted to use **MIDI-files**.

To sync the steps I need an **event for each time** in the music and would then show the next step. In this case I wouldn't use the Timer anymore.

I already looked at **NAudio**. I found tutorials for playing MP3-files which don't help me. I created a **MidiFile-object** but I don't know how to play it. I know that a MIDI-file contains information on how to play the music (for synthesizers) but I don't want to implement my own player.

1. What is a **simple** way to **play** a MIDI-file with NAudio?
2. How can I **receive Events** in each time of the music?
3. Is there an **alternative** to NAudio that can probably help me better?
4. Is there an alternative to MIDI that can sync to my visualization?

I am thankful for every kind of help. I've been searching for a while and think that I am maybe looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) (I'm the author) playing MIDI files along with firing played events is pretty simple:

```
namespace SimplePlaybackApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Playback _playback;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("The Greatest Song Ever.mid");

            var outputDevice = OutputDevice.GetByName("Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth");

            _playback = midiFile.GetPlayback(outputDevice);
            _playback.EventPlayed += OnEventPlayed;
            _playback.Start();

            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => !_playback.IsRunning);

            Console.WriteLine("Playback stopped or finished.");

            outputDevice.Dispose();
            _playback.Dispose();
        }

        private static void OnEventPlayed(object sender, MidiEventPlayedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... do something
        }
    }
}
```

More info in [Playback](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/playback/Overview.html) article and [Playback API](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia.Playback.html) reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get deeper into the midi internals this looked like a pretty cool library and source code to explore.

http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/